# Window.print on Epson lx 300+II continous roll paper

Tags: javascript, php, printing, epson, dot-matrix

I want print a web page with window.print (javascript) i want to print the document to the roll paper, page width the problem has been solved, but the page height is the problem if i print just 1 row data, too many wasting the paper,

example :

```
+-----------------+
|data is here     |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

how can i set the printer stop when all of data has been printed?

like this :

```
 +-----------------+
 |data is here     |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 +-----------------+
```

or maybe i how can i set the paper height auto (responsive / dynamic) ?

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you go around it? Do you solve it?

Comment: @ArjunPrakash nope.. i can't solve it...